# Adiabatic Index ($C_{p}/C_{v}$) Through Phase Change

Tags: thermodynamics, fluid-dynamics, phase-transition, thermal-conductivity

Does the adiabatic index change when a phase change happens?

For example, when we have a compressible liquid (say CO$_{2}$) inside a pipe that goes from high pressure (100 bar) to low pressure (1 bar) in an orifice which causes the liquid phase to change into solid/vapor mixture. In this case, does the adiabatic index ($C_{p}/C_{v}$) change, and why?

Comment: Different phases have different material properties, so the [relation between the heat capacities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Relations_between_heat_capacities) also changes.

Comment: Thank you for your kind response! How do I calculate the new heat capacities? Say that I have the pressure, density and temperature and enthalpy of first state (before expansion) and I have the pressure, enthalpy (which will be same as state one assuming its adiabatic expansion) of second state. Please note that the density will change upon the phase change and also the mass quality, this is is where I am struggling in.

Comment: You are aware that a phase change is equivalent to an infinite heat capacity (Dirac delta function of T), right?

Comment: Hi Chet, thanks for your comment. Actually I do not know, it will be great if you elaborate more!. I am tackling the problem from fluid mechanics/thermodynamics point of view. I do need need to know the heat capacity "during" the phase change where the heat capacity is infinity, I need to know the heat capacities before and after the phase change point and I believe it is not infinity right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The heat capacities are a function of temperature.
Consider ,

Cp(*T*) = a + b*T* + c*T²* . . .

And
Cv(*T*) = A + B*T* + C*T²* . . .

If you divide the two , you shall get that the adiabatic index is not just a constant .

About the index for different phases thus shall obviously mean that it's not going to be same as can be seen from wikipedia   https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heat_capacity_ratio

Comment: Thanks Abbas, this was helpful.